# Post not working React + Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, react-on-rails

When I try to make a post I'm getting a 400 (Bad Request) Error.

I'm trying to post a new Player into a Team.

My controller

```
def create
@teams = Team.find(params[:team_id])  
@players = @teams.players.new(player_params)
  render json: @players
end

private
 def player_params
     params.require(:player).permit(:name, :photo, :nationality)
 end
```

The function

```
_handleSubmit = async (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
const teamId = this.props.match.params.id;
const payload = this.state.players;
console.log(payload);
try {
  const res = await axios.post(`/api/teams/${teamId}/players`, payload);
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
 }
};

_handleChange = (e) => {
const newState = { ...this.state.players };
newState[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
this.setState({ players: newState });
};
```

Comment: If you know the request is hitting the right controller, I would check `player_params` in the controller and `payload` in your JavaScript. Since you have `player_params`, it sounds like you're using strong parameters which throws a 400 Bad Request if required parameters are missing.

Comment: I edited my functions and now I'm not getting the 400 Bad Request error but nothing is getting posted to my database.

Comment: When you `console.log(payload)`, what does that look like?

Comment: I get exactly what I typed in the form.

Comment: Ok, that's great. Based on your controller, it's expecting something like `{ player: { name: "", photo: "", nationality: "" }`. Is that what your server is receiving?

Comment: I don't think so. I check my api and nothing new appears. What can I do to find out?

Comment: Have you checked your logs? You can check your development.log file to see what data is getting sent to your controller.

Comment: Ah, I just realized you're calling this `@teams.players.new(player_params)`. Calling new won't create a new player. If you want to create a record in the database, you'll want to use `@teams.players.create(player_params)` instead.

Comment: That's it! It's posting now. Except for the photo but I'll figure that out. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to strong compare what the body you send, and what the body you expect to receive on the server?

On backend you can send not only error code, and error message, or field identifier which error occurs.

And don't forget to set `await` statement if you will work with query result:

```
const res = await axios.post(`/api/teams/${teamId}/players`, payload);
```